# git push rejected, merge conflicts, git pull --rebase

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I'm trying to push my commit, but couldn't since there is another commit (same-level in the HEAD race :)

I know I need to merge those two commits together, not exactly sure how to do it.
I already tried `git pull --rebase`.

My [GIT-CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eDAE.png):

[image: git cli]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need to need to do is solving the conflict you see mentioned at the end of your `pull --rebase`.
See "[HOW CONFLICTS ARE PRESENTED](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_how_conflicts_are_presented)": you will have to open those files, and remove the conflict markers.
For the `.tern-port` file, you need to decide if you want to keep your file, and remove it, as it has been removed in the upstream repo.

> I forgot to configure my `.gitignore` file.

If you realize that because of tracked files that should not be tracked, don't forget to un-track them first, before adding them to your `.gitignore`

```
git rm --cached -- afile
echo afile >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
```

That can be done during your conflict resolution stage.

Once that stage is done, add them (`git add .`), and continue the rebase (`git rebase --continue`).
After that, if the `git status` is clean, you can push.

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer, it looks like git pull --rebase, MARKED conflicting lines, in each of those files. And you also made me realize I forgot to configure my .gitignore file.

Comment: @Dapf_maz I have edited the answer to added the .gitignore configuration.

Comment: I see, so that's how you delete a file from git repository, using .gitignore. leaving the local copy undeleted. Nice!